# Create randomized page design in a songbook

Tags: formatting, songs

I want to create a songbook, using either the package `songbook` or the package `songs`, because every song must have guitar tabs (and I want to have the possibility of adding notes to the songs later). Now I want to do something special: I have several drawings as pdf or jpg, and I want to decorate the border of the pages with these drawings. But they should distributed randomly over the book, e.g. on page 1 drawing 1 is used, on page 2 drawing 5, on page 3 drawing 2 etc.

Now my question is: How can I create a page layout where these drawings are used as borders and furthermore they are distributed randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `everypage` package provides a hook via which you can place an image on every page.  (For a usage example, see the `draftwatermark` package by the same author.)  If the choice of image must be random, the `lcg` package implements random number generation.

All three packages should be compatible with both `songs` and `songbook`.  (I loaded them successfully using `songs`, and I assume `songbook` would work just as well.)